# Перезапускается loadInBAckground в Loader, при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android, android-loader

У меня есть `Loader`, создаю и вызываю его так:

```
mLoadData = getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, bundle, this);
mLoadData.onContentChanged();
```

При первом запуске все хорошо: запускается конструктор, `onStart`, `doInBackground` и, в конце, я получаю данные в активность. Но когда я поворачиваю экран — перезапускается `loadInBackground`, а потом вызывается два раза метод `onLoadFinished` в активности (она слушатель). Как сделать так, чтобы, при повороте экрана, я получил или ссылку на `Loader`, который уже существует, или получил данные, через метод `onLoadFinished` (можно эквивалентный), которые были загружены ранее, без перезапуска `loadInBackground`?

Comment: У вас не `Loader` перезапускается, а при повороте вновь вызывается `onContentChanged()` и данные обновляются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22299373/3212712), докам и здравому смыслу `onContentChanged()` говорит лоадеру, что данные изменились и их надо заново загрузить. Т.е. вам надо запускать лоадер методом его запуска (sic!) `forceLoad()` вместо того, что используете вы. В этом случае лоадер не перезапустится после поворота экрана и будет каждый раз выдавать только уже загруженные данные, если они есть.

Comment: Эм... А зачем `forceLoad`? У меня и без него, при повороте, вызывается "onLoadFinished", не перезагружая "doInBackground".

Comment: @bukashka101, без `forceLoad` у вас задача ни разу не запустится и данные вы, засим никогда не получите.

Comment: Кстати, я вызываю `onContentChanged()` в `onCreateLoader`, а `forceLoad` стартую в конструкторе `Loader'a`.

Comment: @bukashka101, делать это **точно** не надо. Ни onContentChanged вам не надо вызывать совсем, ни forceLoad в конструкторе. Вам надо `mLoadData = getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, bundle, this);` и `mLoadData.forceLoad();`

Comment: Ну тогда можно хоть в `onCreateLoader` это делать?

Comment: @bukashka101, зачем? Это бессмысленно. onCreateLoader должен согласно названию только создавать лоадер. Это как если бы конвейер на автовазе сразу после закручивания последней гайки в новой машине её бы заводил и нажимал на газ. Можно так сделать, но это уменьшит общую разумность мироздания.

Comment: Но... У меня без `forceLoad` метод `onLoadFinished` вызывается сам. Это нормально?

Comment: @bukashka101, по идее нет. Видать вы forceLoad  где-то в классе лоадера зачем-то вызываете.

Comment: Поставил я `forceLoad`, но он, при каждом вызове, вызывает `loadInBackground`. Лучше верну-ка я его в `onStartLoading`...

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, наверное там надо перед его вызовом проверку делать на предмет уже идущего процесса или того, что данные уже пришли...

Comment: Я в `onStartLoading` засунул, все работает хорошо. `loadInBackground` грузит только раз, `onLoadFinished` вызывается при каждом `initLoader`!

Comment: @bukashka101, если это то, что вам нужно, то слава богам)

Comment: Во имя девятерых! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, ага) Не забудьте за меня на выборах проголосовать, кстати)

Comment: Ууууууу, Вы хотите стать модератором, я всеми ногами за Вас!

Comment: То есть руками...

Comment: @bukashka101, хоть чем, главное за)))